# Positioning the slidejs caption

Tags: jquery, css, caption

I am using [slidejs](http://slidesjs.com/) and trying to figure out how to position the slidejs caption below the image.  I can't figure out how to do this.   I'm in trial-and-error mode with the css file with no luck.  below is my css.

```
/*
       Caption
*/
.caption {
  z-index:500;
  position:absolute;  /* remove this and caption dissapears. why? where does it go? */
  left:-39px;
  bottom:-10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  left:0;
  width:440px;
  text-shadow:none;
}

.caption p {
  bottom:20px;
  z-index:500;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

1. Does anyone know how to do position the caption somewhere else on the page?
2. The closest hint I found is [here](http://groups.google.com/group/slidesjs/browse_thread/thread/e37b5e85afedf270/bc83afa22a33b5c9?lnk=gst&q=caption#bc83afa22a33b5c9).  But I'm a javascript and css beginner and I really don't get it.  Can someone explain what they are saying?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `left` and `bottom` properties of `.caption`:

```
.caption {
  z-index:500;
  position:absolute;  /* remove this and caption dissapears. why? where does it go? */

  left:-39px;         /* horizontal positioning relative to the parent nearest
                         explicitly positioned elements left border */
  bottom:-10px;       /* vertical positioning relative to the parent nearest
                         explicitly positioned element bottom border */

  font-size: 1.1em;
  width:440px;
  text-shadow:none;
}
```

***Also*** remove the extra `left` definition...

Comment: I tried that. Modifying the `bottom` property of .caption has absolutely no effect.  Neither does `top`.  I also tried your suggestion on `.caption p` and no effect.  Its frustrating because that should work but I have no idea why not.  ??

Comment: Oh yes, the `left` property does work but all text gets chopped off at the edge of the image.

Comment: I'd have to see *all* the code associated to give a complete solution or you could debug it yourself in the `chrome dev tools`

Comment: The page is located at http://107.22.173.10  with minimal passwd protection because its not accepted yet.  user: test pass: testme.   Click 'digital' you will see the slidejs.  I use firebug and I can't figure out anyway to move the caption in the vertical direction.

Comment: http://107.22.173.10/digital.html user:test pw:testme has a block of text "The caption belongs here".   I am trying to move the caption to replace that text.  Thanks!  I am excited to get this very frustrating problem solved.